# 'int' object is not iterable on Django Template

Tags: python, django, for-loop, conditional-statements

**'int' object is not iterable** I'm getting this error on my template, I understand, *i think* what it means - the condition: `{% elif User_No_Auth_Tld > 0 %}` cannot allow the `for()` loop to loop over the results(`{% for NotAuthDomain in User_No_Auth_Tld %}`), but I tried: `{% elif User_No_Auth_Tld %}` (without an integer condition), but still get the same error.

What am I doing wrong below?

Thank you

```
{% if not User_Tld_Entered  %}  <!-- show ADD TLD form -->      
    <hr />
    #form here
    <br />
    <h4>Verify your domain</h4>

{% elif User_No_Auth_Tld > 0 %}

    <h1>display unauth domains, with auth link</h1>
        {% for NotAuthDomain in User_No_Auth_Tld %}
            {{ NotAuthDomain }}
        {% endfor %}
{% elif User_Auth_Tld %}
   #form here.
{% endif %}
```

**For future users who might run across this post for help:**
I ended up changing the declaration for `User_No_Auth_Tld` to not use the `.count()` method for a db record(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not about the condition, it's about the iterable itself. 
Ensure that `User_No_Auth_Tld` is not `int`, but `list`, `dict` or any other iterable.

Comment: User_No_Auth_Tld is a variable being passed from a view. Declaration is User_Tld_Entered = Tld.objects.filter(Client_id=request.user).count()

Comment: Just what I've said - `.count()` method returns integer.

Comment: does this indicate its not an int? (This is a set of db obj. from a db table)

Comment: I removed .count() and all is working. I guess db results are then not INT and are just that objects :)

Comment: No problem. Consider accepting the answer then. And also you'd like to  read more on iterables in Python, as well as PEP, as your code style looks a bit lacking.

Comment: sounds good, still early on with python :) . Thanks for the suggestions here.